# Cannot Composer Install with Symfony - PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I had a problem with my Ubuntu so I needed to install back everything.
Nearly all is done but when I start a new project with Symfony on PhpStorm, and when I do a `composer install` or `composer update` in the terminal I have an error that I don't know how to treat.

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception



[RuntimeException]                                              
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:



    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the global namespace.                                                      
  Did you forget a "use" statement? in /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:52                                                                          
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                               
  #0 /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(284): Symfony\Component\Config\Util\XmlUtils::loadFile('/var/www/html/E...', Array)       
  #1 /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php(41): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseFileToDOM('/var/ww  
  w/html/E...')                                                                                                                                                                                              
  #2 /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php(57): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->load('web.xm  
  l')                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  #3 /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php in /var/www/html/Eval2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/  
  Config/Util/XmlUtils.php on line 52
```

I tried installing composer following this [link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx)
but I don't recall using such practice.

So I cannot move forward with my project because I can't get past composer... if anyone knows why and could give me a step-by-step approach that would be truly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's DOMDocument library is not installed. You need to install it. Try -

```
sudo apt-get install php-dom
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I do the command it says "Impossible to find php7-dom package"

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? And What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: PHP 7.0.13-0 ----- Ubuntu 0.16.04.1

Comment: Its working! I just did your command line without the "7" ! Thank you! :)